# Cannot set POST request headers to JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress, http-headers, content-type

I am using WordPress `wp_remote_post` to try to and set the POST request payload to a API as JSON.

The API is rejecting the request because it receiving the request as "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "Content-Type: application/json"

I have tried setting the content type as JSON and running `json_encode` on the body of the request but to no avail.

I'm not sure what else to try. Can anyone provide me with a pointer here?

```
function call_api_test( $endpoint = '', $args = '' ) {
    $api_url = get_field( 'api_url', 'option' );
    $request = array(
            'grant_type'=> 'client_credentials',
    'client_id'=> get_field( 'api_client_id', 'option' ),
    'client_secret' => get_field( 'api_client_secret', 'option' )
    );
    $token_response = wp_remote_post( $api_url . '/oauth/token', array(
    'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf8'),
    'body' => json_encode($request),
    'data_format' => 'body',
    'sslverify' => false
));
$token_object = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($token_response));
$request_url = $api_url . '/' . $endpoint . '?access_token=' . 
$token_object->access_token . '&' . $args;
$api_response = wp_remote_get( $request_url, 'sslverify=0' );
$response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $api_response ) );
return $response;
}
```

I expect the request headers to have a content type of application/json but instead they are application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Are you calling 3rd API?

Comment: I am doing something similar but using `application/json; charset=utf-8` for the `Content-Type`. (Note hyphen in `utf-8`). Could it be that without the dash the content type is unrecognized and defaulting to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?